# How do I source multiple files without overwriting my current environment?

Tags: r, file

I have 2 .R files that contain several functions and I have an additional file where  I want to use these functions to analyse some data. If I do it like this:

```
source("path_file_A.R")
source("path_file_B.R")
```

`ls()` only returns the objects from file B so `source()` seems to overwrite the current environment. Is there a way to source both files without overwriting it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do two files have duplicated object names? If so, you need to make these names distinct, or source two files to different environments.

Comment: No I named all objects differently to avoid overwriting.

Comment: `source` does not clean the environment unless you have the explicit instruction to delete all the objects from the current environment in "path_to_file_B.R"

Comment: If thats true, `source`  deletes all objects by default, since I only used the default settings. Also, according to the R-documentation there is no setting that instructs to empty the workspace.

Comment: @Loco, I mean, make sure that the code in the file "path_to_file_B.R" does not contain any instructions to clear the environment, e.g. `rm(list = ls())`

Comment: agree with @DzimitryM.

Comment: @DzimitryM  Thats the exact problem. The code in File B cleared the environment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an environment to `source` with the `local` argument.

```
e = new.env()
source(
  "path_file_A.R",
  local = e
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about that aswell and will do so if there really is no way to source both files to the same environment. But if I had like 100 files it clearly seems unpractical to me to pass a different environment for each file.

Comment: @Loco Well you could re-use the environment if you want to source them all to the same place! Could do something like `lapply(list_of_paths, source, local = e)`. If you want to source them each to their own environment, it's not too hard to make a list of environments and just name them the corresponding file names.